# How to enable a click event on first colum of ng-grid on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

How to enable a click event on first column of ng-grid on page load.

All fields are coming dynamically .And i used ng -grid

i tried these

```
$('.colt0').find('.icon-sort').click();
$('.colt0').find('.icon-sort').trigger('click');
$('.colt0').trigger('click');
$('.colt0').on('trigger' ,'click');
```

but not working....

Please suggest.

Comment: please post your related HTML codes too..

Comment: <div class="gridStyle adminUserList" ng-grid="gridOptions" ></div>  ,using angular ng-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.colt0', function(){
    //do something
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using *delegated events* for this:

```
$(".colt0").on("click", ".icon-sort", function(event){
    // will fire for dynamically loaded .icon-sorts
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. ...

and

> ... In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements
>   not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their
>   potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be
>   monitored.

Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Comment: unfortunately it is not working , actually i have to click the column on page load ..but ng-grid is not allowing that